# GatsbyJS + Netlify Form doesn't receive submissions

Tags: javascript, html, forms, gatsby, netlify

So, I have a website that I'm hosting on Netlify. I followed the documentation that they have on their site (about the forms) and the form's name shows up on my Netlify dash after deployment but none of the submissions are going through.

Can I please have some help with this?

Here is the form that's in my Contact.js component:

```
<form
  name="contact-me"
  method="post"
  action="/success"
  data-netlify="true"
  data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
>
  <input type="hidden" name="bot-field" />
  <label htmlFor="name">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required />
  </label>
  <label htmlFor="email">
    Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
  </label>
  <label htmlFor="message">
    Message: <textarea name="message" id="message" required />
  </label>
  <footer className="major">
    <ul className="actions">
      <li>
        <button type="submit" className="button small special">
          Send
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        {/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
                    <button type="reset" className="button small">
          Clear
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</form>
```

Of course, I'm using Gatsby to build the site.

Please let me know if I should put the link to my repo here.

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious if you've solved your problem. I'm encountering the same problem right now...

Comment: Hey Ben. I did actually yes. To be fair I still don't know what the issue was since I followed their documentation but after repeating and trying with incognito mode I ended up with the code you see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to test what netlify will see using a Gatsby site:

- disable javascript in your browser for the site
- go to the contact page using no javascript
- view page source (page netlify uses to register form)
- view form and make sure the value exist for what [Netlify requires](https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/)
- Requires `data-netlify="true"` in form

```html
<form name="contact" method="POST" data-netlify="true">
  <p>
    <label>Email: <input type="text" name="name" /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Message: <textarea name="message"></textarea></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type=”submit”>Send</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

If it is setup correctly, your form should process correctly in the SPA and register the input fields correctly.

Comment: When I follow your points here, I see that the `data-netlify="true"` attribute seems to be gone from my form (it was there before) and a new form field is added `<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact">`. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I have the same issue as the creator of this issue, but it works for me if I *disable* Javascript. With Javascript enabled, I receive error 404 - very strange

Comment: Ok, found the issue - with Javascript enabled the form-name parameter is missing in the post request.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution was to ensure the my web worker was being loaded after my manifest in `gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        ...
      }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-offline'
  ]
}
```

Source: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-offline-support-with-a-service-worker/

This package was also helpful in building the form: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-netlify-form